# Bing Places Holiday Hours

Tags: bing

I am working for a client with around 50 listing on Google My Business and Bing Places. Google My Business has an option which allows you to schedule 'special hours' in preparation for shut downs over the holidays. Had anyone been able to do this in Bing Places?